# Проверка наличия файла в директории с помощью jQuery в приложении Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

Есть приложение Flask. В части Python происходит обработка файла .wav по кускам. На каждый кусок создается txt файл с текстом. К этой функции идет роутинг @app.route("/", methods=['POST']) и ajax-запрос. 
Задача сделать с помощью jQuery динамическое обновление общего результата на странице html, т.е. надо, чтобы результаты по каждому из кусков, по мере появления, добавлялись в блок на странице.
Пыталась это реализовать с помощью вот такого кода (см. ниже), используя параллельные ajax-запросы,  но работа цикла, почему-то, происходит не так, как должна бы. И вообще есть зацикливание. И  флаг не обновляется по завершению основного ajax-запроса.

Код:

```js
var k;

function python_script_work(file){
  var flag = true;
  var downloadLink = blobUri +"/"+ container +"/"+ file;
  var t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/',
    data: {"file": downloadLink},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
      result_text = response;
      var t2 = (new Date()).getTime();
      delta = t2-t1;
      flag = false;
      console.log("Флаг стал " + flag);
      show_display_of_result(file, result_text, delta);
      // return response;
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      result_text = 'Увы, распознавание текста не удалось :(';
      show_display_of_result(file, result_text);
      // return 'Увы, распознавание текста не удалось :(';
    }
  });
  console.log("Идем параллельно с ajax");
  var file_path = "static/load_files/text/"+file.split('.')[0]+"_Result";
  // console.log(file_path);
  k = 1;
  while (flag){
    console.log(k);
    console.log("Флаг = " + flag);
    console.log("Проверяем маленький файл под номером " + k);
    // tmp_flag = midtermResultExists(file_path + "_" + k + ".txt", k);
    $.ajax({
      url: file_path + "_" + k + ".txt",
      success: function() {
        console.log("Mini-File exists");
        jQuery.get(file_path + "_" + k + ".txt", function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
        k = k+1;
        return true;
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("Mini-File doesn't exist");
        return false;
      }
    });
    console.log("Проверка файла " + file_path + "_" + k + ".txt");
  };
  return;
};
```

В результате получается вот такое зацикливание
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: У вас сейчас миллионы запросов в секунду уходят. Проверьте вкладку `Network` в DevTools.